# uploading and downloading a file(Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, download

i am not able to download my uploaded file, when i click on the file i get the error "Couldn't find Newsletter without an id". this is my code

### controller.rb

```
     class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_newsletter, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   # GET /newsletters
    # GET /newsletters.json
   def index
     @newsletters = Newsletter.all
   end

   # GET /newsletters/1
    # GET /newsletters/1.json
   def show
   end

   # GET /newsletters/new
  def new
     @newsletter = Newsletter.new
     end

    # GET /newsletters/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /newsletters
    # POST /newsletters.json
     def create
      @newsletter = Newsletter.new(newsletter_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @newsletter.save
       format.html { redirect_to @newsletter, notice: 'Newsletter was successfully    created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @newsletter }
    else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @newsletter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
  #file download
 def document_download
  @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:id])
   file_path = @newsletter.document_download
    if !file_path.nil?
send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/system/documents#{params[:id]}/original/#{file_path}",  :x_sendfile => true
  else
     redirect_to newsletters_url
   end
  end
 # PATCH/PUT /newsletters/1
  # PATCH/PUT /newsletters/1.json
  def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @newsletter.update(newsletter_params)
     format.html { redirect_to @newsletter, notice: 'Newsletter was successfully       updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
       else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @newsletter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
   end
 end

# DELETE /newsletters/1
  # DELETE /newsletters/1.json
  def destroy
  @newsletter.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to newsletters_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
   end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_newsletter
  @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:newsletter_id])
   end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   def newsletter_params
    params.require(:newsletter).permit(:document, :year)
  end
end
```

### index.html

```
   <tbody>
   <% @newsletters.each do |newsletter| %>
     <tr>

    <td><a href="/public/newsletters/document_download/", style="text-decoration:none"> <%=newsletter.document_file_name %></a></td>
      <td><%= newsletter.year %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', newsletter %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_newsletter_path(newsletter) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', newsletter, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you    sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

### show.html

```
     <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <p>
    <strong>Document:</strong>
  <%= document_download_newsletter_path(@id_or_model_itself) %>

  </p>


    <p>
   <strong>Year:</strong>
   <%= @newsletter.year %>
   </p>

 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_newsletter_path(@newsletter) %> |
 <%= link_to 'Back', newsletters_path %>
```

### form.html

```
    <%= form_for(@newsletter) do |f| %>
     <% if @newsletter.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@newsletter.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this newsletter from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @newsletter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :document %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :document %>
    <%= f.file_field :document %>
     </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :year %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :year %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

### routes.rb

```
      resources :newsletters do
    get :document_download, on: :member 

end
```

### model(newsletters.rb)

```
   class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :document
    validates_attachment_presence :document
    validates_attachment_content_type :document, :content_type => [ 'application/pdf','text/plain']


    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read your full code but based on the error you've mentioned, the problem is in your `set_newsletter` method.  Since this is `NewslettersController` and assuming you haven't manually set a different primary key for `Newsletter` model, you should be using `params[:id]` and not `params[:newsletter_id]` as follows:

```
# app/controllers/newsletters_controller.rb

def set_newsletter
  @newsletter = Newsletter.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

Comment: i still get the same error "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NewslettersController#document_download couldn't find newsletter without an id". i've updated my code for "set_newsletter" (replaced "params[:newsletter_id]" with "params[:id]") but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated response (1st December 2013):**

Based on our comment, I again looked at your code and came across this line in index.html (index.html.erb I assume):

```
<td><a href="/public/newsletters/document_download/", style="text-decoration:none"> <%=newsletter.document_file_name %></a></td>
  <td><%= newsletter.year %></td>
```

It looks like you are referring to a newsletter document name but not passing the newsletter id in href. Your show.html (show.html.erb) seems to be correct, but I don't see where you are initializing the value for "@id_or_model_itself".

Can you modify these parts and verify if it works?

**Original Response**

In the "set_newsletter" method, you are trying to get the id of newsletter using "params[:newsletter_id]", but in case of "document_download" action, you are using "params[:id]". I suspect that is the reason behind the issue. Try to use "params[:newsletter_id]" in document_download as well.

Comment: i've updated my code as you said i've changed "params[:id]" in document_download to "params[:newsletter_id]" but the error remains"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in NewslettersController#document_download couldn't find newsletter without an ID"